# tabularray and \gappto

Tags: tabularray

As a new command, I use `\problem` to typeset tests for my math students. Sometimes I also include how many credits you can gather at a certain problem. If I use the `credits` key, everything works just fine. But I also have a `\task[<credits>]` command that I can print minor questions and their credits with (see MWE below).
The problem I'm currently facing is that the credits given with the `\task` command will be put multiple times instead of only once.
Do you have any tips? Thank you!

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xifthen}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularray}
  \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, counter}

\makeatletter
\def\credit{}
\newcounter{WS@credits}
\setcounter{WS@credits}{0}
\newcounter{subtask}
\setcounter{subtask}{1}
\renewcommand{\thesubtask}{\alph{subtask})}
\newcommand{\task}[1][]{%
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{%
        \thesubtask%
        \stepcounter{subtask}%
    }{%
        \thesubtask%
        \addtocounter{WS@credits}{#1}%
        \ifnum\arabic{subtask}=1%
            \gappto\credit{(#1~p)}%
        \else%
            \gappto\credit{\\(#1~p)}%
        \fi%
        \stepcounter{subtask}%
    }%
}

\newcommand{\problem@credits}{}
\define@key{problem}{credits}[\problem@credits]{\renewcommand{\problem@credits}{%
    \addtocounter{WS@credits}{#1}%
    (#1~p)%
    }%
}

\newcounter{probctr}
\setcounter{probctr}{1}

\newcommand{\problem}[3][]{
    \setkeys{problem}{#1}%
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={>{\bfseries}lX}, column{1}={leftsep=0ex, rightsep=1.5ex}, column{2}={leftsep=0ex, rightsep=0ex}}
        \tikz[remember picture, baseline=(probctrbox.base)]{%
            \node[anchor=north west] (probctrbox) at (0,0) {A\arabic{probctr}};
        } &
        {#2}%
    \end{tblr}%
    \tikz[remember picture, overlay]{%
        \node at (probctrbox.south) [below, font=\scriptsize\normalfont]{\parbox{7ex}{\centering\ifdefempty{\credit}{\problem@credits}{\credit}}};
    }
    \stepcounter{probctr}
    \setcounter{subtask}{1}
    \renewcommand{\credit}{}
    \renewcommand{\problem@credits}{}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\problem[credits=3]{
Write as power expressions.

\begin{tblr}{colspec={*{2}{>{\bfseries}lX}}, column{odd}={rightsep=0ex}}
    \task & $2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2$ &
        \task & $3\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 3$
\end{tblr}
}{
\begin{tblr}{colspec={*{2}{>{\bfseries}lX}}, column{odd}={rightsep=0ex}}
    \task & $=2^4$ &
        \task & $=3^6$
\end{tblr}
}

\problem{
Write as power expressions.

\begin{tblr}{colspec={*{2}{>{\bfseries}lX}}, column{odd}={rightsep=0ex}}
    \task[1] & $2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2$ &
        \task[3] & $3\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 3$
\end{tblr}
}{
\begin{tblr}{colspec={*{2}{>{\bfseries}lX}}, column{odd}={rightsep=0ex}}
    \task & $=2^4$ &
        \task & $=3^6$
\end{tblr}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: well tabularray processes its argument more than once to measure the cells. There is some new code to test for the measuring phase, https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/179#issuecomment-1399695943 that you could try, but personally I think that with tikz and (nested!) tabularrays you are using the slowest and most difficult code for a rather simple layout. Why don't you check the task package?

Comment: I guess that I just use my previous ``\problem`` command that is based on a tcolorbox instead.
The ``task`` package is a good advice, thanks for that. I also found the ``xsim`` package that seems to be very useful.

Comment: PS: I tried the code you were linking to, but it doesn't work.